# Python type hinting not generating error for wrong type when running the code

Tags: python, python-3.x, type-hinting

I was recently checking about type hinting and after reading some theory I tried a simple example:

```
def myfun(num1: int, num2: int) -> int:
    return str(num1) + num2


a = myfun(1, 'abc')
print(a)
# output -> 1abc
```

Here you can see that I have defined `num1` and `num2` of type int and even after passing `num2` value as string it is not generating any error.

Also the function should expect to return `int` type value but it's not complaining on returning string type value.

Can someone please explain what's going wrong here?

Comment: Python doesn't check any of the type annotations. If you just run the file normally, the hints are just for readers (and you can also access type hints within code, e.g. with [typing.get_type_hints](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.get_type_hints)). To really use the type hints, use a tool like [MyPy](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) which is a static analyzer.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

It's called type **hinting** for a reason: you're giving a *hint* about what a variable should be to the IDE or to anyone else reading your code. At runtime, the type hints don't actually mean anything - they exist for documentation and usability by other developers. If you go against the type hints, python won't *stop* you (it assumes you know what you're doing), but it's poor practice.

Note that this differs from statically-typed languages like Java, where trying to pass an argument that's incompatible with the function's definition will produce a compile-time error, and if you pass a differently-typed but compatible argument (e.g. passing a `float` to a function that expects an `int`) it will be automatically typecast.

Note that the code you've given will encounter a `TypeError` if the programmer uses it like they're supposed to, because `int` cannot be concatenated to a `str`. Your IDE or linter should be able to see this and give you a warning on that line, which it does based on the type hints. That's what the type hints are for - informing the behavior of the IDE and documentation, and providing a red flag that you might not be using a function in the intended way - not anything at runtime.